# Pythonでデータフレームをエクセル出力する際、説明文を入れたい

Tags: python, pandas

データフレームが複数個あり、to_excelでそれぞれ別のシートに出力しています。
また、各々のデータフレームについてそれぞれ説明文を1行程度入れたいと考えていますが、
説明文の入ったデータフレームをそれぞれ縦結合するとデータが崩れてしまい、うまくいきません。
どのようにすればきれいに説明文を入れることができますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。
[image: 画像がやりたいことのイメージです。]

Comment: 要望そのものの機能は無さそうですが、この辺が参考になるかも。[Is it possible to read excel comments with Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56010234/9014308), [how can i write comments on some cells of excel sheet using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36397805/9014308), [worksheet.write_comment()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html?highlight=comment#write_comment), [write_string(row, col, string\[, cell_format\])](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html?highlight=cell%20wrtie#write_string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ドキュメント](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)に書かれていますが、`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel()`の第1引数には文字列のパスでなく[ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)オブジェクトを使うことが可能です。ExcelWriterオブジェクトの`book`プロパティはopenpyxlの[Workbook](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html)であるため、これを直接使ってセルを操作できます。

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [1, 2, 2, 3], 'x2': [2, 3, 1, 5]})

with pd.io.excel.ExcelWriter('path/to/my/book.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=2, index=False)
    writer.book['Sheet1']['A1'] = 'ここに説明文を入れる'
```

Comment: `to_excel`の`startrow=2`に対応して[pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) の時に`skiprows=2, header=0`を指定する説明を加えれば読み書き共に完成と思われます。[pandasで複数行ヘッダーを持つExcelファイルを読込みカラム(columns)を整形する](https://qiita.com/noca/items/966f4c5ae5eee8195fe0)

Comment: `engine='openpyxl'`
を指定しないとエラーになるようですね。

Comment: ご参考までに、pandas 1.1現在では、xlsxwriterがインストールされていればxlsxwriter、なければopenpyxlをデフォルトのバックエンドとして使っているようです。上のコードではopenpyxlを明示的に指定していますが、指定しない場合、お使いの環境によって`writer.book`はxlsxwriterのWorkbookになっているかもしれません。その場合も、xlsxwriterのAPIを使って同様のことが可能と思います。